# A Technique to share data received from network call between multiple activities

Tags: android

Currently I'am developing app which having a bad API. I have a situation where I have to use data received from network call in a activity, which is 2 steps away from the activity where I made the network call. In other word all the data necessary fill 3 activities comes on this one network call.

So I pass necessary data between activities using `Intent Extra`. It is not easy to maintain and It takes noticeable time to switch between activities.

I know one possible solution is to store data in database. and access those data from different activities. It feels like a bad practice because no use of those data after user pass 3rd screen.

Is there any better technique to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You can put all your network logic in the separate class, cache data in some variable and use it in your activities (you can use singleton class or injecting by dagger).

Also you can read about Clean Architecture and get some good practices from it.

If you don't want use anything from above, you can remove data from database after using and not store it forever. Or you can use `SharedPreferences` if your data is not complex.